# How to show items from wiki page library and document library on 1 page

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, content-query-web-part

How to show items from wiki page library and document library on 1 page in sharepoint 2010. I tried CQWP but it helps with either of it.

Comment: do you want to show the links to wiki and document from 2 different lists on a single page?

Comment: yes i want to show the  links

Answer (score 0):

If we use the content query web part, we can only display items from one list type, so we cannot display the wiki page library and document library in the same content query web part.

To show items from wiki page library and document library on the same page, we can use linked source in the SharePoint designer.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

WAYS TO DISPLAY MULTIPLE DOCUMENT LIBRARIES.

https://wonderlaura.com/2009/01/29/ways-to-display-multiple-document-libraries/

SharePoint 2010: How to Link Two Lists and Create a combined view.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15258.sharepoint-2010-how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view.aspx